# How to create two related radiobuttons?

Tags: symfony

The code below creates 2 radiobuttons, however they are not related to each other. One is rendered with a name `description_form[friend]` and the other one with the name - `description_form[guide]`. How can they be rendered with the same name? The [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/radio.html) is not clear about this subject.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('friend', RadioType::class, array(
                'label'    => 'Friend',
                'required' => false
            ))
            ->add('guide', RadioType::class, array(
                'label'    => 'Guide',
                'required' => false
            ));
    }
```

Comment: Use choices, expanded true, multiple false. ChoiceType::class

Comment: What is the point in RadioType then?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using a list of `RadioType` is not quite easy, that's why everybody recommends you to use a `ChoiceType` which dynamically creates a radio list depending on an array of choice data.

When you create a `FormTypeInterface`, it has to represent (commonly) one field or one sub form in a global form, so each field name has to be unique to be mapped to the corresponding data.

The `buildForm` method allows to add some sub fields in you `FormType`, in your case the field holds two sub fields as radio button and each has a specific name, this is intended by default, but you should always keep in mind the global array data you want to deal with.

Here's your example :

```
class MyCustomFormType extends \Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('friend', RadioType::class, array(
                'label'    => 'Friend',
                'required' => false
            ))
            ->add('guide', RadioType::class, array(
                'label'    => 'Guide',
                'required' => false
            ));
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix
    {
        return 'my_custom';
    }

    // ...
}
```

So this form type data should look like :

```
$myCustomFormData = array(
    'friend' => $friendData,
    'guide' => $guideData,
);
```

And nested in a global form it would be :

```
$formData = array(
    'my_custom' => $myCustomFormData,
);
```

But you can name the field as you want :

```
// In a controller extending \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add('custom_field', MyCustomFormType::class)
    ->getForm();

// Then
$form->setData(array('custom_field' => $myCustomFormData));
```

Note that currently, since you map "friend" and "guide" data to `RadioType` they should hold a boolean value as :

```
$myCustomFormData = array(
    'friend' => true, // checked
    'guide' => false, // unchecked
);
```

But how would you unselect a value then ?

You should had a placeholder to do that, and handle it while submission...

Also, changing the name can be done using the `finishView` method of your type class, it takes the `FormView` (built view of your type), the form itself and the options as arguments :

```
public function finishView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
{
    $childName = $view->vars['full_name']; // "my_custom" by default

    foreach ($view as $childView) {
        $childView->vars['full_name'] = $childName;
    }
}
```

But you would also need to add a `DataMapperInterface` to get back the submitted value to the form type itself instead.

To do all that, you need to know how the Form Component works and it's not easy.

## Easy way

So I agree with the other answers, you should use a `ChoiceType` to get it out-of-the-box.

I assume your custom form type is about choosing either a "friend" or a "guide", so it could look like this :

```
$builder
    ->add('fellow', ChoiceType::class, array(
        'choices' => array(
            'I have a friend' => 'friend',
            'I\'d like a guide' => 'guide',
        ),
        'expanded' => true, // use a radio list instead of a select input
        // ...
```

Have a look at [the official docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html)

Then your data will look like :

```
$form->add('custom_field', MyCustomFormType::class);

$form->setData(array(
    'custom_field' => 'friend',
));
```

When rendered the "friend" choice will be selected and you will be able to change it to "guide".

An array of choices for the `choices` options takes labels as keys and choice values as values :

```
<div id="form_custom_field">
    <input type="radio" name="form[custom_field]" value="friend" checked="checked">
    <label>I have a friend</label> 
    <input type="radio" name="form[custom_field]" value="guide">
    <label>I'd like a guide</label>

...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems, that the `ChoiceType` is the best solution indeed. But I can't understand, why does `RadioType` even exist then?

Comment: `ChoiceType` is an example of implementation using it. But you could write anything based on the From component and that's its beauty.

Comment: A `RadioType` just extends a `CheckboxType` and represents the corresponding html input. They help dealing with boolean values.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do radio buttons in Symfony 2.7 , hope it helps you.

```
   $yes_no = array('1'=>'Yes','0'=>'No');

   ->add('myfieldname', 'choice',array(
        'choices' => $yes_no,
        'label'=>'YourLabelGoeshere',
        'required'=>true,
        'expanded'=>true,
        'multiple'=>false,
        'placeholder'=>false
))
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps consider using the `ChoiceType` field.

See here: [Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html)

This allows you to output the options as radio buttons if you choose.

Comment: What is the point in RadioType then? And I have difficulties customizing ChoiceType style

Answer (score 0):

`RadioType` is used internally by `ChoiceType`. In most use cases you want to use `ChoiceType`.